# Build a .sln / .vcxproj project from command line with a free edition of Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, build, msbuild

If I don't want to use the features of the Visual Studio IDE, is it possible to install **a non-time-limited** / non-30-days-limited-demo of a Microsoft C++ compiler (which version?), and **build a .sln or .vcxproj project directly from command line?**

Here is what I succesfully use for single .cpp file projects:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
cl helloworld.cpp /link user32.lib
```

Is there a way to extend this to .sln or .vcxproj projects?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition:  https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/  Fully featured including command line building and server / continuous build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use `devenv` for this.  Note that, at least with VS 2017 Community, you must open the VS gui and sign in with a Microsoft account, otherwise it will stop allowing compiles after 30 days.

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE
devenv Solution.sln /build Debug /project project
```

(This also works even if you don't run `vcvarsall.bat`, which is nice)

Comment: You're right: My VC++2013 Express was in "30-days demo mode expired" state, but just logging to a Microsoft account solved the problem. So this means I'll probably be able to keep VC++2013 and use your `devenv` idea, awesome!

Comment: Interesting... I did not even know there was a limit. Every once and awhile I login to the live account.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to *not* use the IDE, it's possible to install just the VS Build Tools (the installer is named `vs_BuildTools.exe` for VS2019), and then just use `msbuild`.

Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-using-msbuild-to-create-a-visual-cpp-project?view=msvc-160

build.bat:

```
MSBuild.exe helloworld.vcxproj /p:configuration=release /p:platform=x64
```

helloworld.vcxproj:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="16.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>    
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="main.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="main.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Targets" />
</Project>
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello, from MSBuild!\n";
   return 0;
}
```

and an empty main.h file.

No .sln file is really needed in this case.

Comment: Did you have to add MSBuild.exe's directory to your `PATH`?